# Ошибка во время запуска SFML программы на Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, sfml

Программа начинает выполняться, отображается окно. Потом зависает,завершается с [этой](http://errorco.de/win32/ntstatus-h/status_heap_corruption/0xc0000374/) ошибкой. Код:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
int main()
{
   sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: окно нужно закрыть

Comment: @dreamIIx, я прописывал это. Окно все равно зависает и не закрывается

Comment: У Вас нет обработчика событий, поэтому и зависает. Возможно Вы хотели создать окно с помощью `sf::RenderWindow`?

Comment: @dreamIIx `sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Test");
 while(window.isOpen()){
  sf::Event event;
  while(window.pollEvent(event)){
   if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed){
    window.close();
   }
   window.clear();
   window.display();
  }`                                                                                                                                       
   я такое запускал - результата тот же